# Mysql, PHP: Use "WHERE NOT IN" for associative array

Tags: php, mysql

I have sent a stringified associative array from the client side, for example:

```
[{placeId: 1, stateId: 2}, {placeId: 1, stateId: 3}, {placeId: 2, stateId: 4}, ...]
```

In the server side, I received it by using `json_decode`.

Now what I want is, delete everything from a table where rows does not exists in the array request.

For a plain array (`[1,2,3,4]`) and single column lookup(say, `placeId`), I can query it like this:

```
DELETE FROM table where placeId NOT IN [1,2,3,4]
```

But how should I do it when looking up 2 columns`(placeId, stateId)` and comparing it to an associative array like above?

Comment: Loop over your received array and create a separate array containing only the `placeId` values. This can be done easily with a for loop or using array_map. Afterwards, join the values as per normal

Comment: 1) What is **precise** MySQL version? 2) What is the reason to process JSON on PHP? provide it to MySQL as-is if it is correct JSON from MySQL looking point. 3) Provide a sample (a table with some data as textual CREATE + INSERT, JSON value, desired final data state, explanations).

Answer (score 0):

Sure. Look at here.

```
$json = [{placeId: 1, stateId: 2}, {placeId: 1, stateId: 3}, {placeId: 2, stateId: 4}, ...];
$array = json_decode($json, true);
$firstColumn = array_column($array, 'placeId');  
$secondColumn = array_column($array, 'stateId');
```

And use follow query.

```
DELETE FROM table where placeId NOT IN $firstColumn AND stateId NOT IN $secondColumn
```

Of course, the request is written incorrectly, but you must understand how you will execute it in PHP, I'm just showing you that it really works